# how to binding getter value into HTML?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

This is my getter:

```
get diff(): number {
  if (this.budgetTotalDiffList) {   
    return this.budgetTotalDiffList.reduce((a, b) => (a ? Number(a) : 0 + b ? Number(b) : 0), 0);
  }
}
```

And this is my parent HTML:

```
<td>            
  <p>{{diff}}</p>
</td>
```

I have a child component to emit the budgetTotalDiffList to parent getter:

```
this.budgetTotalDiff.emit(Number(this.calculateNewForecastListTotal() - this.oldForecastListTotal));
```

when I change the child budgetTotalDiff, an error show up:

> ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'null: 0'. Current value: 'null: -156546.0056374371'. "

Although the new budgetTotalDiff value can emit to parent, UI value doesn't change until i click the mouse.(so weird)

I try to google the error, it is about the lifecycles hook. most people set time out, but it's not work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve your mouse event problem by using change detection in angular.

Write this code in your parent component.

import this

```
private ref: ChangeDetectorRef
```

Then write this line in your output function in parent component after set value

```
this.ref.detectChanges();
```

And also in HTML call function like this

```
{{diff()}}
```

Comment: well, it's work and the result is what i want,thank!!!!! 
but i think this is a hard fix ??
still  wanna know what make this error T_T
thank

Comment: No this is normal fixed, and if your problem solved than accept the answer, thanks

Comment: errer still here, but the number did change

Answer (score 1):

**diff()** is a function you should call like function. this is not bind value. you can use this like {{ diff() }}.